# Sequence of bounded Operators (Is this a counterexample?)

Tags: operator-theory, banach-spaces, examples-counterexamples

I've to proof the following statement

> Let $X,Y$ be to banach spaces and $(T_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq L(X,Y)$ a bounded sequence of bounded linear operators. Further it exists a dense subset $D \subset X$ of $X$, such that for all $x \in D$ the sequence $(T_kx)_k \subset Y$ is a cauchy sequece in $Y$. 
>   Proof that there exists exactly one bounded linear operator $T \in L(X,Y)$, such that $(T_k)_k$ converges strong to $T$.

But I think I've a counter example. Can somebody verify this or if its not a counter example explain to me why not?

Choose for a bounded region $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ with smooth boundary $X = H^1(\Omega), Y = L^2(\partial \Omega), D = C^{\infty}_0(\Omega)$ and define for $k \in \mathbb{N}\colon T_k f:= (-1)^k T_{\partial \Omega} f$ where $T_{\partial \Omega}\colon H^1(\omega) \to L^2(\partial \Omega)$ is a sobolev trace operator which is bounded and linear. Now $\|T_k\|$ is the same for each $k$ and by that the sequence is bounded. Further $D = C^{\infty}_0(\Omega)$ is dense in $X$ with $\forall f \in D \forall k \in \mathbb{N} \colon T_k f = 0$ in $Y$.

Now choose $f \in X$ with $ \|T_{\partial \Omega} f\|_Y > \epsilon$ and see for each $k=2n$ that $\|T_k f - T_{k+1}\|_y = 2 \|T_{\partial \Omega} f\|_Y > \epsilon$ and by that the sequence cannot converge strong.

Comment: So how is the sequence in Y Cauchy? Are you arguing that it is a constant sequence?

Comment: yes it's constant zero in $Y$

Comment: OK and how do you know then that there exists an f in X satisfying the property stated in the last line?

Comment: Take any $f$ that is not zero on the boundary. For example a constant $f  \in H^1$ like $f =1 $ everywhere. Omega is bounded and by that such $f$ are in $H^1$ since their derivative vanishes

Comment: And you are certain it says "exactly one" and not "no more than one" or something to that effect? And when you say "series" you mean "sequence"? Is there any more context to the problem?

Comment: yes it says exactly one.

Comment: oh sorry yes, i mean sequence thank you.

Comment: I don't know what a Sobolev trace is. But you seem to imply that it is zero in a dense subset. If a bounded operator is zero on a dense subset, it is zero everywhere.

Comment: It seems like from Wikipedia that the Sobolev trace operator is only defined on open bounded subsets: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_operator. However, any open subset of R^n is in general not complete, but I'm not sure if that is of any importance in determining whether or not $H(\Omega)$ could be complete hence Banach or not -- I don't know enough about Sobolev spaces admittedly to say. Everything else seems correct as far as my limited knowledge can discern -- yeah reading the definition it seems like it doesn't matter that $\Omega$ is open, H can still be complete/Banach.

Comment: $H^1$ is for sure a banach space :)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what is wrong in my example. Of course $D$ as I defined it is not dense. I mixed up two spaces and didn't saw it later on. Thanks for any comment - they helped alot to rethink my example!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a counterexample. Let $X=Y=H$ be an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\{e_j\}$. Let $T_k$ be the projection onto the span of $\{e_1,\ldots,e_k\}$. Let $D$ be the span of $\{e_1,e_2,\ldots\}$.

For each $x\in D$, for $k$ big enough $T_kx=x$, so the sequence $\{T_kx\}$ is Cauchy. As we have $T_kx\to x$, we have $T_k\to I$ pointwise. But the converse is not uniform:
$$
\|I-T_k\|=1
$$
for all $k$.

I cannot comment on your example because I have no idea what a Sobolev trace is. But you seem to imply that it is zero in a dense subset. If a bounded operator is zero on a dense subset, it is zero everywhere.

Comment: I mean the trace operator https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_operator. In your proof you need D to be a subspace, I don't have it given as a subspace. But my example is even with a subspace

Comment: I have to admit that it is not the best time of the day for me; but, why would I need $D$ to be subspace?

Comment: $T$ dont even defines a linear operator on $D$. What if $x,y \in D$ with $x+y$ not in $D$? What if $0$ not in $D$ and so on.

Comment: I still don't see where I would need it. The operator $T$ is linear by construction, so it extends immediately to the span of $D$. In any case, to prove that $T$ extends to all of $X$ I need to do $$\|Tx_k-Tx_j\|=\|T(x_k-x_j)\|\leq c\|x_k-x_j\|.$$ The first steps requires linearity: if $x,y\in D$, then $$T(x-y)=\lim T_k(x-y)=\lim T_kx-T_ky=Tx-Ty.$$ Where do I use that $D$ is a subspace?

Comment: for example T(x-y) may not be defined if x-y not in D. And that is possible if its no subspace. D must conain 0 and all linear combinations of it's elements. Further a linear mapping must map between vecotr spaces by definition

Comment: But, if $D$ is as in the statement of your question, so is its span (linear combinations of Cauchy sequences are Cauchy).

Comment: we can go back to trhe definition of "linear mapping" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map. It has to map between vector spaces. So if D is no vectorspace you cant define a linear mapping on it.

Comment: But (like I said already) I can define it on its span. Regarding your example, you keep ignoring the fact that you are (erroneously) claiming that you have a bounded linear operator that is zero on a dense subset and is not zero everywhere.

Comment: I have changed the answer to include a counterexample. The issue has nothing to do with $D$ being a subspace or not, but with the uniform convergence.

Comment: I understood the words in brackets wrong in context with the span, so I focused on other points, sorry. Sure you can do it on the span like you said and than it should work. I'm focusing on the reason why in my example I have a dense subspace and a linear operator that is not zero but zero on the subspace, this thing is annoing me the whole time. But just know I got the thought that $C^{\infty}_0 maybe is not dense(I thought so for a long time)